# Wi-fi not working Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, wireless

I am a total newbie.

I managed to install Ubuntu 18.04 on a Dell Inspirion 15, but I have no wi-fi.

I stumbled onto a terminal and typed lshw -C network and got the following:

```
*-network                 
   description: Network controller
   product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
   vendor: Broadcom Limited
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
   resources: irq:18 memory:aa100000-aa107fff


  *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
   logical name: enp7s0
   version: 07
   serial: 74:e6:e2:39:fd:98
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:19 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:aa000000-aa000fff memory:c0000000-c0003fff
```

What next? I'm clueless!

Comment: Try to disable 'secure boot' in the bios settings